# vspace or line space in text of wrap fig

Tags: spacing, picinpar

I am using wrap fig and want to insert a line break within the text.
However, `\vspace` or `\linebreak` or `\break` don't lead to any change.

Here is a sample of my LaTeX code

```
\begin{figwindow}[0,r,%
       {\includegraphics[height=2in]{PascoSynthesizer.eps}},%
       {\label{fig:label} Caption
        }]
\textbf{Electronic Output}:\\
A sum of nine harmonics of sine waves with a\\ fundamental of 440 Hz plus a second output of the fundamental. \\
\vspace{0.3in}
\textbf{Controls:}\\
    \end{figwindow}
```

Comment: Please always post complete (small) document showing packages used the `wrapfig` package does not define a `figwindow` environment, so your title and tag do not match your example.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

`picinpar` is quite an old package with several restrictions, a newer package for these kind of inserts is `wrapfig` however you can force a space by adding a blank line with a strut (or a rule of a specified height if you need finer control).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{picinpar}
 \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figwindow}[0,r,%
       {\includegraphics[height=2in]{PascoSynthesizer.eps}},%
       {\label{fig:label} Caption
        }]
\noindent
\textbf{Electronic Output}:\\
A sum of nine harmonics of sine waves with a\\
fundamental of 440 Hz plus a second output of the fundamental.\\
\strut\\
\textbf{Controls:}
    \end{figwindow}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Success: the line \strutt\\ worked to produce a linespace. the inclusion of [demo] caused problems and was omitted.              GREAT GRATITUDE!!

Comment: `demo` makes includegraphics just use a black square instead of the picture you should use it when posting examples because we have not got the file `PascoSynthesizer.eps` so can not run the code otherwise. Also in questions please post complete documents as in this answer not fragments that can not be run.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to check your preamble.
If I use:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{picinpar}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
```

and then your code, everything runs well, as you can see from the screenshot below (or isn't this the desired output?):

[image: Screenshot of the output]

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I do have what you show above. What I need is to add a line space between '... fundamental.' and 'Controls'